# Get Stack Traces for J2EE Http requests in Real Time

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, httprequest, real-time, stack-trace

When HTTP requests hit the server, I want to catch the full stack traces at run time, then save them in DB for another purpose. I just tried jstack and visualvm but i'm unable to map stack traces for a http request.

Stack trace should be like [this](https://ptrthomas.wordpress.com/2006/06/06/java-call-stack-from-http-upto-jdbc-as-a-picture/)

[image]

Example of my requirement:

Some Http request(either webservice or servlet) for login  --> a thread starts in Tomcat's JVM ---> Catch the stack trace of this at run time from that thread

**Note**: I need some java code/jar/tool that can capture the stack traces of all the http requests at real time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose [Thread.getAllStackTraces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces()) solves your problem.

PS

Of course you can add some filters to exclude unnecessary threads

Comment: If I use that to get all stack traces, then its not real time right? there will be 100's of users using my web app and they will be hitting different requests and my requirement is whenever there a request to my webapp I have to catch it/log the full stack trace of it.

Comment: As I can understand you, you have to bind stack traces with HTTP requests. The simplest way is change thread name. You can use HTTP filter. It should set thread name to specific string before starting business logic, and reset name later.

Comment: OK, got it..Is it possible to get stack traces without touching the webapp code base, i just want to run an independent java code or jar and get all stack traces?

Comment: Yes you can call `Thread.getAllStackTraces` from different webapp. But if you want change thread name then filter have to live inside original webapp.

Comment: ok thanks nick... i will check it out and then tick the answer